# Find a fundamental sytem of solutions to a given homogeneos differential equation

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Given the first order homogeneous linear differential equation, $$x'(t) = A(t)x(t), \,\,A(t)=\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{-2}{t} & \frac{1}{t} \\
 \frac{3}{t} & 0
\end{pmatrix}, \,\,\,t>0,$$

I want to find a fundamental system of solutions. In the literature I only find guesses for such solutions in the way of finding a general solution to a nonhomogeneous differential equation. In case the matrix $A$ is not dependent on $t$, the eigenvalue setting for $A$ provides the fundamental system. Even though I know the fundamental system of solutions to this differential equation, I would like to determine it. In the results, i.e theorems, concerning the variation of the parameter $t$, one usually aims at finding a particular solution of the nonhomogeneous counterpart.

Can somebody provide a procedure or a solution proposal for the fundamental system of solutions to the homogeneous differential equation given above ? Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A first step is to ask whether the various $A(t)$ commute with each other; if they do then the fundamental matrix for an IVP initialized at $t_0$ is just $e^{\int_{t_0}^t A(s) ds}$. If they don't commute then I don't believe there is a general recipe.

Here it is easy to see that they do commute with each other because they are just scalar multiples of one another. Actually, just changing the time to $u=\ln(t)$ reduces this to a constant coefficient equation.

Comment: I appreciate your answer. I have two questions. If one computes the exponential that you provide, one gets the exponential of a matrix. The first issue here are the integral limits since the antiderivative that one gets is the logarithm which is not defined in 0. The second issue is the fact that the exponential of a matrix is represented as a power series of the matrix. I do not see how to find the fundamental system in a closed form. The second question: which variable change do you suggest given $x'(t)=A_1x(t)1/t,$ where $A_1$ has now only constant entries?

Comment: @user996159 1. You can start at some other $t_0$ instead, it is not important. 2. In general simplifying the exponential is not trivial, but here it is because the integral is just $\ln(t/t_0)$ times a constant matrix. 3. The change of variable I'm talking about is to change the time variable to $u=\ln(t)$ since $\frac{dx}{dt}=\frac{dx}{du} \frac{du}{dt}=\frac{1}{t} \frac{dx}{du}$, so $x(u)$ satisfies a constant coefficient equation.